# Android, libgdx and box2d basics

Tags: android, box2d, game-physics, libgdx

I wrote couple of simple board games since i started on android learning, Please let me know is there any tutorial or links, where i can start with physics library with libgdx, looking for something like basics of physics with libgdx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start with the official documentation at the [libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d). That will get you up and running with some basic examples. Once you're beyond the basics, using the [box2d manual](http://box2d.org/documentation.html) will fill in all the details. It's very easy to read, and it's not hard to translate C to Java.

Comment: Should have a look here http://rotatingcanvas.com/using-box2d-in-libgdx-game-part-i/

Answer (score 5):

These tutorials might be helpful:
http://decisiontreegames.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/using-box2d-in-libgdx-game-part-i/

Comment: http://decisiontreegames.wordpress.com/ is marked private by its owner. Can I get an invitation?

Answer (score -1):

You may find very useful information about how to use box2d in android in this book - Android NDK Beginner's Guide

Comment: That book is for using the NDK. Using box2d with libgdx (where it is integrated) is going to be a whole different ballgame.