# Android Studio - error: package java.awt.geom does not exist

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am migrating an app from Eclipse to Android Studio.  when i compile code like:

```
import java.awt.geom.Area;
```

i get

> error: package java.awt.geom does not exist

build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.droider"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    //compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.3.jar')
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

Any suggestions as to how to solve this?  Is it a gradle issue?  Should i include files and use as library?

Comment: "Any suggestions as to how to solve this?" -- stop using classes in `java.awt.geom`. They are not part of the Android SDK. "Is it a gradle issue?" -- no.

Comment: is this like, an answer?  anyhow, tks!

Comment: I do not know if this is an answer. You claim that you are migrating the app from Eclipse. That suggests that the app used to work. However, `import java.awt.geom.Area;` would be invalid with Eclipse as well.

Comment: it used to work but it is an app that i have not compiled or run for a couple of years now.  since it is dependent on googlemaps api v2, which has since been deprecated, the app does not perform correctly in its current configuration.  but thanks, i am attempting to solve the issue with the `android.graphics` library set

Comment: please post as an answer and it will be upvoted.  i cant guarantee that i will accept as cooreect answer until i have effectively solved the problem.

Comment: this answer...... http://stackoverflow.com/a/13189376/3678308

Comment: @ExceptionLover post as answer and you will get UPVOTED.  tks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@CommonsWare suggested that i not use `java.awt` library and that is probably sound longterm advice.

On the other hand, to solve the problem at hand, i [downloaded the library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm), unzipped the file and placed the jar file (java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar) in `libs` folder.

I then right-clicked on the jar file and chose `Add as library`.

Problem solved.